# Angular2 @angular/cli e2e Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular-cli

My e2e tests were running fine and suddenly* this error is showing up. I have been trying to debug this for a while and is still clueless.

`*suddenly` = Possible upgrade of windows. (not confirmed) &
Changed to new @angular/cli (I believe it worked fine after the update, but cannot recollect well)

- Platform: Windows 10 Pro
- Proxy: Behind a corporate proxy. (Tried setting proxy in CMD while running as Admin)

**Any hints on what would have gone wrong? Any inputs on which direction to go is also appreciated much. I am mostly clueless right now!**

<kbd>proxy.bat</kbd>

```
set PROXY="http://xxxx.xxxx.com:3128"
set HTTP_PROXY=%PROXY%
set HTTPS_PROXY=%PROXY%
```

<kbd>Error Log</kbd>

```
> ng e2e
> ** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:49152 **   0% compiling    10% building modules 0/1    .   .   .
> webpack: Compiled successfully. events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> 
> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400
>     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\xxxxx\xxxx\web\angular\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
>     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
>     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
>     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
>     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:395:11)
>     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

<kbd>package.json</kbd>

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "mavenbuild": "node ./node/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng build --prod --base-href ngrepair-web"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "primeng": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.28",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

<kbd>protractor.conf.js</kbd>

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
      require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e'
      });
    },
    onPrepare() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, the issue was related to proxy settings. Are you behind corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes. I tried setting env vars, etc, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I have posted my fix here check if this works for you. If you need any further explanations let me know.

Comment: @Jeff Got it working?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try it today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have latest `node`, `npm`, `protractor`.

---

To set proxy for npm, add it to your `.npmrc` file (`npm config list` will show the location of user config file) as:

```
proxy=http://proxy_url:port
https-proxy=http://proxy_url:port
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

Use `http://username:password@proxy_url:port` if proxy has authentication

Try either of the following to see if the above change worked:

```
npm config list;//also shows location of user settings file
npm config ls -l;//shows all defaults
```

---

To let protractor pickup your proxy do the following in cmd:
(Related [pull request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/966))

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_url:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy_url:port
```

---

To find proxy url in Windows, open Internet Explorer.

> Goto Tools>Internet Options>Connections>Lan Settings

In the [✓]*Use automatic configuration Script*, you can find a link to a `.pac` file or you will get the proxy url from here itself.In case of `.pac` open the url in browser and open the pac file when it gets downloaded, to the end of the file look for something like:

```
return "PROXY 120.42.240.53:3281; DIRECT";//this is your proxy URL.
```

(this worked for me, but there are different other solutions if you search for it)

---

In addition to these I have also removed `readonly` from the node_modules folder.